# capture wired headset button press event Pocket PC PDA

Tags: c++, pocketpc, headset

I have one question regarding the WIRED Headset button when the wired Headset is connected to a Windows Mobile phone.

How does the Dialer application know that the Headset button is pressed in this scenario?

How to receive WIRED headset button press event into my pocket pc C++ windows mobile application?